# dynamic 2-D array on private attribute C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I want to double the size of a 2-D array in one dimension. I have an 2-d array defined in private members

```
private:
static const int ARRAY_SIZE=2;
static const int NUM_ARRAYS=26;

Profile membersArray[NUM_ARRAYS][ARRAY_SIZE];
```

I want to double the ARRAY_SIZE whenever enough elements are in that row.
In my private method

```
void MyADT::copyAndDoubleArray(){
membersArray= new (nothrow) Profile[NUM_ARRAYS][2*ARRAY_SIZE];
}
```

The following error occurs on

```
error: Array type 'Profile[26][2] is not assignable
```

I assume it has to do with the array being a private attribute. So I think I need to know how to initialize the array allowing dynamic allocation

Comment: You cannot resize C++ arrays.  Their sizes are fixed at compile time.  Either use `std::vector` or similar container type.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Its strange because this is for an assignment and the professor specifically declared we are only allowed to use arrays. I think its an exercise to show the need for linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

No, it has nothing to do member declared as `private` because as seen from your code you are trying to access `membersArray` inside member function.

Start with keeping a pointer to `Profile` in you class and allocate memory in one dimension.

```
Profile *membersArray;
membersArray = new Profile[NUM_ARRAYS*ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Now you can access elements of `membersArray` as `membersArray(x*ARRAY_SIZE+y)` where `x and y` are dimension of the 2D array where `[0 <= x < NUM_ARRAYS] and [0 <= y < ARRAY_SIZE]`

Now if you want to increase the size of existing array then:

```
Profile *temp = new Profile[NUM_ARRAYS*(2*ARRAY_SIZE)];
//You can code here to copy existing elements from membersArray to temp.
//Elements of temp can be accessed as temp(x*(2*ARRAY_SIZE)+y)` where x and y are dimension of the 2D array and [0 <= x < NUM_ARRAYS] and [0 <= y < (2*ARRAY_SIZE)]
//Now delete membersArray. 
delete [] membersArray;
//Now assign new increased sized array to membersArray.
membersArray = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Objects of array type cannot be modified as a whole: even though they
>   are "lvalues" (e.g. an address of array can be taken), they cannot
>   appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator.<sup>[[*]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Assignment)</sup>

So, you need to declare your array using [`new[]-expression`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). You may end up with something like:

```
private: Profile **ppMembersArray;
public: constructor() {
    resize(DEFAULT_ROWS_COUNT, DEFAULT_COLUMNS_COUNT);
}
void resize(int newRowsCount, int newColumnsCount) {
    // allocate some enough memory..
    Profile **ppNewMembersArray = new Profile*[newRowsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < newRowsCount; i++)
            ppNewMembersArray[i] = new int[newColumnsCount];
    // copy the existing data to the new address, release the previous ones, and so on..
}
```